# developing an android application with servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I'm currently developing an android application. My application allows users to choose a picture from a gallery, add a comment and send it to the server. The server then saves it in database.

Currently I'm using `HttpUrlConnection` at client side and `Dynamic Web Project` with a `servlet` to process on server (I'm using eclipse with Apache Tomcat)

So the questions are:

1. Is it a proper use of this technology to develop my app. (does it violate any rules? Sorry I'm a newbie)
2. Does this technology affect anything if i want to expand my app?
3. Are there any better technologies to use in this situation and is it worth to use it?

Comment: You confused me with your 'client-server application'. An application posting something to a website is usually not called a 'client-server application'. Http is a connectionless protocol to begin with.

Comment: @Mariano sorry,my bad.

Answer (score 0):

No I think it is a better way to develop this. I have also develop a chat based app usign the same technologies.

It doesn't violate any rules. There are many apps in the market usign the same technologies.

> Q-3.Are there any better technologies to use in this situation and is it worth to use it?

You can also use php or any other server side scripting language to do the same.
Because when you want to host your java app you may find difficulty for java hosting but for php and asp you can easily find hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

I answer in order:

1- the client is different, the client is recomended create an android application.

2-You need have clear this: Android is an application, the server has to attend petition from android. The conection could be using webservices, API rest, or others ways.

3-Android need Java to be native, in the server side you can use, Ruby, PHP, Java, Python or any server programming languaje side. Is your choice.